# Electronic bike keeps getting flat tire on the back

Tags: tire

A month ago, I got my first flat tire on the back tire on my electronic bike and I have fixed it, it was a Nail. Yesterday I got it again, it was a hole in the whole tire, so I changed the tire and the inside.

Today  I got it again but I see no hole in the tire.

What do you think it is?

Comment: What does the damage to the tube look like? You may have pinched it on installation or something.

Comment: Did you replace the tube when you did the tire?

Comment: @mattnz Yes tube and tire

Comment: Yeah, unless you find a cause (spoke end, wire sticking through tire, pressure too low, etc) I'd recommend you get a belted tire.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an e-bike with a rear hub-motor (and with the battery pack over the rear tire), you should note that you have considerable unsprung weight on that rear tire. You should try to make sure that you have the tires properly inflated -- on the high end of the maximum PSI the tire can handle.

Try to ask your LBS when you're replacing the tire what type of puncture you're getting. If you are getting pinch flats, then you need to think about inflating your tires to a higher pressure. If that's not possible, you can also explore getting wider tires.

If you're getting road debris punctures, then kevlar belted tires will help. Also, as ow3n notes, having some sealant inside your tube might help although I find that this often just creates a huge mess when you get a flat that is too large for the sealant to contain.

Comment: @RoboKarenToday I fixed it, and I asked him what was it, he said he doesn't know he didnt find anything, there was just an hole in the  tube. Is it possible that the spins of the wheel are causing it?

Comment: The spokes or spoke nipples can. He should have made sure they are not poking through.

Answer (score 1):

Head to your local bike shop and ask them to replace your tube with one that has a removable core. Then add some (1-2 oz) Stan's Sealant inside the tube. Air it up, give it a good spin and you will have a tire/tube that can withstand most punctures from random automobile road detritus.  [This looks like a good how to.](http://www.infinitecycles.com/2013/05/adding-stans-no-tubes-sealant-to-tubes/)

Answer (score 1):

If you replace the tyre with a tough (kevlar belted) touring tyre this is likely to deal with debris punctures. These are more likely if the tyre is quite compressed as it rolls because of the flatter contact patch. In addition a touring tyre will be able to run at a higher maximum pressure than a similarly-sized city / general-purpose tyre as was probably supplied, reducing the likelihood of pinch flats. So I suggest a marathon plus tyre on the back - probably around a 35mm or equivalent. I'd put one on the front at the same time.

Also don't forget to unweight the saddle on bent legs as you go over rough stuff (potholes etc.). You might of course just have been unlucky.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a string of bad luck. Two punctures within a month is not unheard of, especially if you're riding in city or other area where debris on the road is common.

The last flat tire is most likely to be problem with installation of the new tire and inner tube. Possible trouble areas are pinched inner tube, valve not lining up properly with hole in rim or something caught between inner and outer tube.

If you can, check the location of the leak in inner tube and see if you can find any marks at the same place in the inside of tire. A bit of stone etc caught between the tire and tube can break the tube but doesn't make a hole in the tire.